# Show github build status in readme.md

Tags: jenkins, github, shields.io

I'm using Jenkins to run my builds, and update the [github status](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) of my projects.

This works fine.

I'd like to show the status of the build using http://shields.io/ on my `README.md`, like Travis does it.

Any thought of how can I do that ?

I don't want to use Travis for my project, I want to keep Jenkins.

Thanks !

Comment: Seems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274293/show-current-state-of-jenkins-build-on-github-repo has some information about how to do it

Comment: Thanks Steven, I  already saw this,  I used this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20977634/2003734

And as said, I'm able to see the result of my build github branch view. But I'd like to see it on the main page of my project, i.e. to insert it in the readme.

Answer (score 3):

Shields.io has progressively added support for Jenkins over the years and now has a variety of badge options available:

- Build status badge:
  [image: Jenkins]

  https://img.shields.io/jenkins/s/https/builds.apache.org/job/commons-lang.svg
- Tests status badge:
  [image: Jenkins tests]

  https://img.shields.io/jenkins/t/https/ci.eclipse.org//jdt/job/eclipse.jdt.ui-Gerrit.svg
- Code coverage badge using the JaCoCo plugin:
  [image: Jenkins tests]

  https://img.shields.io/jenkins/j/https/builds.apache.org/job/Derby-JaCoCo.svg
- Jenkins plugin version badge:
  [image: Jenkins tests]

  https://img.shields.io/jenkins/plugin/v/blueocean.svg

Answer (score 0):

From shield.io's homepage and [it's source code](https://github.com/badges/shields/blob/master/server.js), it doesn't seem to be possible yet.

But shield.io is based on that open source project, so you can send a PR with the integration code. You can [check how other integrations work](https://github.com/badges/shields/blob/master/server.js#L2850-L2892) and add the one you are missing. It shouldn't be that hard.

If you really think you won't be able to do it, you can try [opening an issue](https://github.com/badges/shields/issues) in that repo and hope someone else implements it.