# Change github commit status in Jenkins dsl

Tags: git, jenkins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to change the commit status for a build in Jenkins (I get the sha as parameter build).

I'm using the *DSL plugin* and not the *pipeline plugin*.
I tried using the following solution [How to set github commit status with Jenkinsfile NOT using a pull request builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214730/how-to-set-github-commit-status-with-jenkinsfile-not-using-a-pull-request-builde/47162309#47162309) but I can't make it work (as I don't have the step() phase in the DSL)

```
def setBuildStatus(String message, String state, String context, String sha) {
    step([
            $class: "GitHubCommitStatusSetter",
            reposSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredRepositorySource", url: "https://github.com/<yourRepoURL>"],
            contextSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredCommitContextSource", context: context],
            errorHandlers: [[$class: "ChangingBuildStatusErrorHandler", result: "UNSTABLE"]],
            commitShaSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredShaSource", sha: sha ],
            statusBackrefSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredBackrefSource", backref: "${BUILD_URL}flowGraphTable/"],
            statusResultSource: [$class: "ConditionalStatusResultSource", results: [[$class: "AnyBuildResult", message: message, state: state]] ]
    ]);
}

job('deploy') {

    scm {
        git {
            remote {
                github('owner/repo', 'ssh')
            }
        }
    }
    parameters {
        stringParam('git_commit', null)
    }



    setBuildStatus("In Progress", "PENDING", "Deploy", "\${git_commit}")

}
```

It fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: (deploy_production.groovy, line 9) No signature of method: deploy_production.step() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[$class:GitHubCommitStatusSetter, reposSource:[$class:ManuallyEnteredRepositorySource, ...], ...]]
Possible solutions: grep(), grep(java.lang.Object), sleep(long), dump(), setJm(javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobManagement), getJm()
```

Is there a way to use the GitHubCommitStatusSetter as part of the DSL job? any other way I'm missing?

Comment: Were you able to find the solution for DSL? I have the same issue, we are using DSL and can't get setBuildStatus to work.