# Update GitHub Build Status from local jenkins server

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, github-api

I was wondering if there is a way to have a Build Status ticker on my GitHub Repository's readme file, if the JENKINS SERVER IS RUNNING ON A LOCAL MACHINE?

Comment: Sure. Copy the status to a public server/cdn.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [JENKINS Embeddable+Build+Status+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Embeddable+Build+Status+Plugin) requires to have a public url, you can instead use only the GitHub plugin.

See "[Show current state of Jenkins build on GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24269125/6309)": since [issue 19775](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19775), it should be able to use the GitHub API to directly set the build status.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. Can you please explain this in more detail? I am new to all this!