# Show live state of Jenkins build in Github PR

Tags: jenkins, github, github-api, github-ci

After diving into this post: [Show current state of Jenkins build on GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274293/show-current-state-of-jenkins-build-on-github-repo)

I still haven't found a way to **show the current status of the build (last Jenkins run result) in every PR.**
Meaning that **every** PR will show the status of the build and not just the specific commit that broke it.

This will make the team more aware of the build status and will prevent merging when the build is broken.

Comment: Did you check e.g. https://applitools.com/blog/how-to-update-jenkins-build-status-in-github-pull-requests-step-by-step-tutorial?

Comment: Yes, that's a great one, it just marks commits after build and not every PR

Comment: I think you might want to trigger a build after each commit, and then every update to a PR will trigger a build and the relevant PR status will be updated in the end.