# GitHub and Jenkins Pull Request Check

Tags: github, jenkins

I have a question regarding GitHub checks for Pull Request. I have an integration between GitHub and Jenkins, which each time a Pull Request is opened it will trigger a Jenkins jobs to run. But how do I configure it so that if the Jenkins job is successful, it will pass back a **Check** validation back to GitHub Pull Request as a success as shown in below image?

I created a GitHub App and the Jenkins job is able to trigger during Pull Request, but no status is pass back. I think I am missing a step somewhere, but not sure which.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show current state of Jenkins build on GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274293/show-current-state-of-jenkins-build-on-github-repo)

Comment: hi @ArunKumarB, the post you've provided does give some insight, but it is a bit old and it doesn't really apply to my scenario exactly, does the GitHub check need to be handled manually via API or does Jenkins have plugins to handle them? i also tried some of the method from the answer and it doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: These links may be helpful: [1](https://faun.pub/github-checks-using-jenkins-pipeline-2d8c594dfba9), [2](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-checks/).